# How to use SwiftUI backgroundTask Scene API with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, swiftui, firebase-storage

I have Firebase setup and initialized to work suitably with SwiftUI project.
But when adding the backgroundTask scene modifier to SwiftUI App file, I get the following error where FirebaseStorage makes the app crashes on launch.
The error message is as follow:
FirebaseStorage/Storage.swift:45: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The code of main app is as follow:

```
struct MubadalaApp: App {
    // register app delegate for Firebase setup
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
        
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack(path: $path, root: {
                MainView(path: $path)
            })
        }
        .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("CheckInbox")) { _ in
// background tasks
        }
    }
}
```

it seems the background task is trying to access firebase resources before they are being initialize, but I wasn't able to locate the root cause of this problem or how to refactor the code to solve the issue.

Any of you guys went through such incident or have some expertise to help.

I was trying to identify the sequence of initializing the firebase resources before using the background task but I wasn't able to find a correct path

Comment: Welcome to SO. Two things: Firebase calls always run on a background thread and UI calls are done on the main thread. Second thing is when posting questions please narrow down where the actual issue is. There's nothing in your code related to Firebase Storage - or for that matter Firebase in general so the issue is unclear. Please some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected. Then update the question with the code that is not working and indicate the line that crashes.

Comment: @Jay You are correct, it is the first time trying to get help from this channel, will try to narrow down my issue as maybe it wasn't clear.

my issue is related to the following code added to the App Scene to initiate app refresh when the app is in the background. The code or this modifier is related to backgroundTask of SwiftUI.

Whenever I add this code, the app crashes with the following error message inside the console: FirebaseStorage/Storage.swift:45: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

You are correct there is nothing related to FirebaseStorage

Comment: @Jay I updated my question and removed unrelated code. the issue is related to using the modifier .backgroundTask block.

Whenever I insert this block, the app crashes with the following error message:
FirebaseStorage/Storage.swift:45: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: My issue is not related to the background/ main threads but it is related to executing tasks using firebase resources when the app is in the background (suspended by iOS). so we use the backgroundTask refresh to wake up the app to do some tasks and then get suspended by the iOS system.

Comment: This code `.backgroundTask(.appRefresh("CheckInbox"))` is unrelated to FirebaseStorage. As mentioned above, please do some troubleshooting. Add a breakpoint in your code and step through it line by line examining the vars and code execution along the way. When the app crashes, you'll know what line it was on. *That's* the code we need to see. The code in the question *as-is* works perfectly for me. You may also want to take a look at the SO help guide to clarify the question [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Jay I solved the problem but I don't have an explanation about the solution. The issue is related to calling FirebaseApp.configure(). I used to call this from AppDelegate and the app works fine. but when I added the .backgroundTask, the initialization of Storage.storage() and Firestore.firestore() inside the init of my view model happens to be called before FirebaseApp.configure(). What I did is that I moved the FirebaseApp.configure() from the AppDelegate to the view model init before the initialization of the firebase resources firestore and storage. And it worked without issues.

Comment: I am not sure if this solution is a good practice. but I read the AppDelegate may take sometime to get executed.
This is the init() code after rectifying the issue:
    init(
        context: NSManagedObjectContext
    ) {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        self.db = Firestore.firestore()
        self.storage = Storage.storage()
        self.context = context
        
        super.init()
        
        self.subscribe()
    }

where I removed FirebaseApp.configure() from AppDelegate.

My question, from your experience, is this solution considered a good practice?

Comment: Please take a look at [Get Started with Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/start#set-up-cloud-storage) and note there is only one way to initialize Firebase in Swift or SwiftUI. Deviating from that will result in intermittent operation (e.g. don't) which is what you're experiencing. In this context, *AppDelegate may take sometime to get executed* is an incorrect/misinterpreted statement as it's the entry point into an app.

Comment: @Jay appreciate you time and guidance, thank you.
I came accross an article by peter friese https://peterfriese.dev/posts/swiftui-new-app-lifecycle-firebase/ where there are two different ways to connect Firebase depending on app lifecycle used within UIKit **Appdelegate** vs **SwiftUI** `init()`
Anyhow, to make story short, I moved Firebase.configure() back to AppDelegate as you indicated and removed the backgroundTask modifier (which is causing these issues) and created google cloud functions that get triggered on events. Until I find proper solution for this need.

Comment: The point now is not how to initialize FirebaseStorage but where to insert `FirebaseApp.configure()` specially when using `.backgroundTask` at scene level. Because when using the `.backgroundTask` it is trying to initialize firebase resources before `FirebaseApp.configure()` leading to the issue which I was facing. I was succeeded in inserting `FirebaseApp.configure()` inside the `init()` of the main App struct instead of the delegate (but I am not sure about this solution). I need to investigate further.

Comment: Just for clarification, is the code in your question right after @Main? Did you fully disable swizzling? If not, you need to. Yes, putting `FirebaseApp.configure()` inside `init()` is the proper placement.